# How to reference file as always copy in build output with C# tag?

Tags: c#, solution

I'm forced to work with a tool that generates it's own solution files (`.sln`). The tool is building the solution based on whatever files that end with `.cs`. The problem is that you can't change files properties as the solution gets regenerated each time you rebuild. This means that you can't set files to `always copy` in Visual Studio, as it will be reset the next rebuild.

[image]

After looking online for a while I was wondering, is there a way to reference files as always copy with C# tags?

For example... `Reference.cs`

```
[assembly: AlwaysCopyToOutputDirectory("path/to/my/file.xml")]
```

Is there a tag like this that I can include in my code in order to change the file properties automatically?

Comment: You could edit the project xml file with that attribute.

Comment: All of the project configuration are generated, I don't even have a .csproj, the tag must be in the code, or it will be overwritten

Comment: Well, then you can't do it.

Comment: Create a powershell script for post-build events like copying files

Comment: Yeah, I can't this tool is really a big pile of ****... I guess that I'll have to make a weird workaround, I can't even make a relative path to the output directory as the output directory may change place...